# Java SQL database returns result of datatype Object

Tags: java, sql, database, spring, hibernate

Iam querying a H2-database and i get a list of results back that are of type Object and i cannot convert them to a proper format:

***My VIEW-table that iam querying from:***

```
SELECT * FROM STATEMENTS_DATAPOINTS;
NAME                  DATA_POINTS_ID    DATE        F1      PRECISON    RECALL  
identifiedNeed          1               2017-11-19  0.3     0.5         0.2
identifiedNeed          2               2017-11-12  0.7     0.4         0.15
identifiedNeed          3               2017-11-15  0.5     0.3         0.1 
identifiedNeed          4               2017-11-18  0.6     0.2         0.05
identifiedNeed          5               2017-11-13  0.1     0.2         0.05
identifiedNeed          6               2017-11-14  0.2     0.2         0.05
identifiedNeed          7               2017-11-16  0.4     0.2         0.05
identifiedBackground    8               2017-11-19  0.2     0.4         0.2
identifiedBackground    9               2017-11-12  0.4     0.3         0.15
identifiedBackground    10              2017-11-15  0.5     0.2         0.1
identifiedBackground    11              2017-11-18  0.6     0.1         0.05
identifiedBackground    12              2017-11-13  0.65    0.1         0.05
identifiedBackground    13              2017-11-14  0.77    0.1         0.05
identifiedBackground    14              2017-11-16  0.8     0.1         0.05
identifiedGoal          15              2017-11-19  0.1     0.4         0.2
identifiedGoal          16              2017-11-12  0.4     0.3         0.15
identifiedGoal          17              2017-11-15  0.3     0.2         0.1
identifiedGoal          18              2017-11-13  0.2     0.1         0.05
identifiedGoal          19              2017-11-12  0.5     0.2         0.15
identifiedGoal          20              2017-11-11  0.6     0.3         0.2

(20 rows, 2 ms)
```

Iam querying from inside a java program and ***the result i get back is:***

```
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@328bbd7, [Ljava.lang.Object;@3a89e146, [Ljava.lang.Object;@340d5ed1, [Ljava.lang.Object;@14d6920b, [Ljava.lang.Object;@52667545, [Ljava.lang.Object;@27103d9e, [Ljava.lang.Object;@79b5147b]
```

which are the 20 objects from the Table. I have tried toString() and toArray() but they dont work, what should I do? My goal is to put all these points in a list.

Interface class with query methods:

```
public interface MeasurementRepository extends CrudRepository<Measurement, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT \n" +
        "    measurement_point.date\n" +
        "    , measurement_point.f1\n" +
        "    , measurement_point.precison\n" +
        "    , measurement_point.recall\n" +
        "FROM measurement \n" +
        "LEFT JOIN measurement_data_points ON measurement.id = measurement_data_points.measurement_id\n" +
        "LEFT JOIN measurement_point ON measurement_data_points.data_points_id = measurement_point.id WHERE name='identifiedNeed';", nativeQuery = true)
List<Double> findAllMeasurementDataPoints();
```

I can change List to type String, Integer, Double, Objects and i still get the same result.

***Created new class using JdbcTemplate to query:***

```
public class DatabaseQueries {


@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public List<MeasurementPoint> findAllNeedDataPoints() {

    List<MeasurementPoint> needStatementDataPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    String query="SELECT  measurement_point.date,measurement_point.f1, measurement_point.precison, measurement_point.recall\n" +
            "FROM measurement \n" +
            "LEFT JOIN measurement_data_points ON measurement.id = measurement_data_points.measurement_id\n" +
            "LEFT JOIN measurement_point ON measurement_data_points.data_points_id = measurement_point.id;";

    List<Map<String, Object>> rows=jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
    for(java.util.Map<String, Object> row :rows) {
        MeasurementPoint measurementPoint = new MeasurementPoint();
        measurementPoint.setDate((String)(row.get("DATE")));
        measurementPoint.setF1((Double)(row.get("F1")));
        measurementPoint.setPrecison((Double)(row.get("PRECISON")));
        measurementPoint.setRecall((Double)(row.get("RECALL")));
        needStatementDataPoints.add(measurementPoint);
    }
    return needStatementDataPoints;
}
```

}

***Iam getting NullPointerException***, it cant find any values, have I missed anything? Error points on this:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rows=jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
```

***The result iam getting now is:***

```
[com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@58e52b28, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@fa8c696, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@5b06cf3c, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@3d89bc9e, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@4cc46c6c, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@5919f14, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@6883cfb5, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@189ee377, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@77d64b04, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@7e3603d5, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@8be95c1, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@67d44afa, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@221fb36f, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@6cf92452, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@1015a491, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@55d3aff3, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@a08faed, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@2f76844a, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@127a9c19, com.ibm.fk.textanalys.MeasurementPoint@5a9e0592]
```

***New results iam getting now :***

```
[MeasurementPoint{f1=0.3, precison=0.5, recall=0.2, date='2017-11-19'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.7, precison=0.4, recall=0.15, date='2017-11-12'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.5, precison=0.3, recall=0.1, date='2017-11-15'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.6, precison=0.2, recall=0.05, date='2017-11-18'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.1, precison=0.2, recall=0.05, date='2017-11-13'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.2, precison=0.2, recall=0.05, date='2017-11-14'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.4, precison=0.2, recall=0.05, date='2017-11-16'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.2, precison=0.4, recall=0.2, date='2017-11-19'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.4, precison=0.3, recall=0.15, date='2017-11-12'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.5, precison=0.2, recall=0.1, date='2017-11-15'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.6, precison=0.1, recall=0.05, date='2017-11-18'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.65, precison=0.1, recall=0.05, date='2017-11-13'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.77, precison=0.1, recall=0.05, date='2017-11-14'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.8, precison=0.1, recall=0.05, date='2017-11-16'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.1, precison=0.4, recall=0.2, date='2017-11-19'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.4, precison=0.3, recall=0.15, date='2017-11-12'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.3, precison=0.2, recall=0.1, date='2017-11-15'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.2, precison=0.1, recall=0.05, date='2017-11-13'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.5, precison=0.2, recall=0.15, date='2017-11-12'}, MeasurementPoint{f1=0.6, precison=0.3, recall=0.2, date='2017-11-11'}]
```

Comment: Include the code how you fetch the data.

Comment: I don't think it is doable that way. `MeasurementRepository` is not a right place to have this method. In this repository Spring knows how to map values to `Measurement` objects. Probably you could have a `List<Object>` that you would parse manually but it's still rather bad place to have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface MeasurementRepository extends CrudRepository<Measurement, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT date, f1, precison, recall " +
          "FROM measurement " +
          "LEFT JOIN measurement_data_points ON measurement.id = measurement_data_points.measurement_id " +
          "LEFT JOIN measurement_point ON measurement_data_points.data_points_id = measurement_point.id WHERE name='identifiedNeed';", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Measurement> findAllMeasurementDataPoints();
}
```

But recommend you to use `JdbcTemplate` for you query and use it with custom mapper. 
`jdbcTemplate.query(your_query, (rs, rowNumber) -> { ... your mapping here ... })`

where (rs, rowNumber) is a lambda expression for `RowMapper<T>` interface.

```
@Service
public class MeasurementRepository {
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate template;

    public List<Measurement> findAllMeasurementDataPoints() {
         template.query(your_query, (rs, rowNumber) -> {
              Measurement measurement = new Measurement();
              ... your mapping here ....
              return measurement;
         })
    }
```

Comment: Is rs and rowNumber variables that comes with the method or that I have to create and how?

Comment: You just need to implement a `RowMapper` interface and extract your data.
Here is the link: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html

Comment: Is JdbcTemplate autowired correctly? Or is in NULL?

Comment: How do i check that? I added where the error points on my new edit

Comment: You can use your debugger. Just set a breakpoint and the execution will pause there.

Comment: Mark your MeasurementRepository with @Service annotation, because for now it is not a Spring managed bean.

Comment: I did but still throws nullpointer and points at that particular code that i linked,Maybe datatypes in the List<Map<String,Object>> are wrong?

Comment: No, the returning datatype is correct. 
Could you try to implement that RowMapper anonymous class with 
`jdbc.query()` method?

Comment: LoL i forgot to use @Autowired in the class that i was using this query method...I get a result back now but the result is another type of Object that cant be read.. Check my edit

Comment: `List<MeasurementPoint> needStatementDataPoints = new ArrayList<>();`

 You are mapping into this type explicitly. Your method returns a list of MeasurementPoint, is this behaviour incorrect?

Comment: Yes my method returns a list of MeasurementPoint, But how doesnt it read the values properly. Do i need to change any datatype somewhere or?

Comment: What does it "mean doesnt read it properly"? Could you override `toString` method on MeasurementPoint class and check the fields?

Comment: I added a toString method to MeasurementPoint and now it reads properly but it seems that its a List with another List inside with the values. Is there a way to just return 1 list? or is this returning correct? Check my new edit for the result iam getting back

Comment: The data were read properly. `toString` method just changes the displaying behaviour! Now you have only 1 list with MeasurementPoint objects inside